# Add items to the selectManyMenu from an input text

Tags: jsf-2

I want to add items from an input text in a selectMany, so I manage to take the value into the backing bean with the ajax tag.
The selectManyMenu value is an Map var.

but when I put this code in the method I call with ajax, sector is the value from the input text where I add the items.

```
public void addSector (){
    sectores.put(sector,sector);
    System.out.println(sector);
}
```

But the view from the selectManyMenu does not add the items. I want to add such items with the input text, can someone give me heads up, I appreciate that.

Comment: To avoid the obvious, you're re-rendering the select many menu by ajax?

Comment: yes, I use a ajax tag in my inputtext. Also the ajax tag use a listener to call the method addSector I previous posted and as render  attribute the id of the manymenu!

Comment: Okay. Aren't you doing other things in the getter method than returing the property? By the way, it'd be helpful if you have posted an SSCCE from the beginning on. The cause of the problem is absolutely not visible in the very marginal code posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I manage to solve this issue,
The backing bean needed to be **ViewScoped or SessionScoped**, It is just matter of logic, I could not retain the previos added value, because the request session view.

I hope this finding help any others!

Comment: You didn't said that the problem was that it didn't remember the previously added items. You said that it didn't add any items at all (which implies, also not of the current request). Your problem description was simply bad.

Comment: My bad man, it just only change the manymenu with the recent input! An important description missing. Getting in to jsf world!! And loving it! thanks any way